# How to keep context in the RetryPolicy thread created by datastax driver

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I am customizing the retry policy by implementing the datastax [RetryPolicy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.7/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/RetryPolicy.html). I've noticed that when triggered, the retry policy is executed in a new thread created by the datastax framework. Thus, I am losing my context and cannot link between the original query execution, and the current retry execution (my relevant context data is stored on [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).)
Is there a way to register/pass data into the retry policy to be able to utilize information from the original query?
My end game is to be able to log relevant context information from the flow of the original query.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed retry policy methods are invoked on an internal driver thread, so you can't use a `ThreadLocal` to share context.

What you can do instead is wrap your statements in a custom [StatementWrapper](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.7/com/datastax/driver/core/StatementWrapper.html) that stores that information in final fields.